# Vue 3 How to pass slots through multiple components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a huge table reusable throughout my project with specified cells.
I want to pass my different cell components into my table component.
But I can't figure out how to pass a named slot **through more than one child**.
I'm using **Vue v3.2.45**

I'm expected to be able to use the slotProps of my named slot `cell` in App.vue
Like I did with `id` with the named slot `test`

[I made a playground to make myself clear here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
// App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { ITable } from './types.ts'
import Table from './Table.vue'

const table = ref<ITable>({
  tree: [
    { data: [{ value: '0' }, { value: '1' }, { value: '2' }, { value: '3' }] },
    { data: [{ value: '0' }, { value: '1' }, { value: '2' }, { value: '3' }] },
  ],
})
</script>

<template>
  <Table :table="table">
    <template #cell="{ cell }">
      Hello {{ cell.value }}
    </template>
    <template #test="{ id }">
      <div class="row">Row above is {{ id }}</div>
    </template>
  </Table>
</template>
```

```js
// Table.vue
<template>
  <div class="table">
    <template v-for="(row, rowI) in table.tree" :key="rowI">
      <Row :row="row" />
      <slot name="test" :id="rowI" />
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
// Row.vue
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" v-for="(cell, cellI) in row.data" :key="cellI">
      <slot name="cell" :cell="cell" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This won't work since all your cells would be populated with the same slot - since they all have the same name - you need to use a cell ID for the name of the slot.

Comment: @BernardBorg but its working fine with the named slot `test`, I got different ids in App.vue

Comment: But all the cells will get the same slot content when you make this work (which I know is possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose the `cell` slot in your `Table` component and use it in `App.vue`

```html
<!-- Table.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="table">
    <template v-for="(row, rowI) in table.tree" :key="rowI">
      <Row :row="row">
        <template #cell="{ cell }">
          <slot name="cell" :cell="cell"></slot>
        </template>
      </Row>
      <slot name="test" :id="rowI" />
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```